Standalone AI program to remove music and noise from videos
I am currently using WhisperAI to do subtitles, and argos-translate to translate, and they work reasonably well, but one thing that peeves me is people putting their own music, or musak, onto videos, often louder than the people talking in them. Are there any offline stem splitter apps for this? Even for just the audio, which I can then put back into the videos.
